# Rails 4 - find_by_* does not work in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I'm running a rake task and stop with byebug upon creation of last product.

Then I get strange discrepancies between output in rake task buebug and rails console.

**Product.count** works both in the console and byebug, but **Product.find_by_id** only works in the console. In rake task it returns **nil**.

So far I replaced find_by_* methods with where, so that validations will pass and the rake task will do its job.

Googling didn't help. This is strange because we use find_by_* in quite few places. Finding out that your validations in a rake task are not reliable is a bit worrying to say the least.

Has anybody encounter such problem before? Any ideas how to proceed further?

Comment: As an aside, you should not be using the `find_by_*` methods. They have been considered a bad practice for a long time. You *especially* should not be using `find_by_id`. Use `Model.find(id)`.

Comment: We use Product.find_by_code. I used find_by_id to prove that other find_by_* methods do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All dynamic methods except for find_by_... and find_by_...! are deprecated.

All the methods that have xxx_by_ are now xxx_by (remove the underline on end-method). So, you can use:

- find_by... and find_by...! or
- where(...).to_a that returns a array or where(...).last to return a object

Note that where(...) returns a relation, not an array.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html